# Puppet uses the hostname as a variable value

Tags: puppet

I have this simple function:

```
define e::x($x = $title) {
  file {$x:
    path => "/tmp/${x}",
    ensure => present,
  }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
e::x {"xxxx":}
```

And yet the file created is /tmp/"hostname", like debian-vm or something.
It NEVER uses the correct value.

I don't get what's wrong, does anybody have any clue ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

So, after some more testing it looks like the $x = $title does not work.
If I use directly $title it works.

This is weird, as I'm sure I already used this pattern on another server without trouble.

Maybe this has to do with my version of Puppet. I run the packaged version of Puppet on Debian Squeeze. There may be a bug.

Comment: I've used this pattern, albeit using `$name` instead, numerous times on Puppet 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian Squeeze packages Puppet 2.6.2 - the `$title` variable won't work as a parameter's default value.

Per the note after the example [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/definedtypes.html#defining-a-type), 2.6.5 is needed to get the expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you. Still does not explain why it then decides to use the hostname as a value, it's weird.

Comment: @VincentRischmann I'm guessing dynamic scoping is to blame for that - `$title` from a higher scope is inheriting down and being used instead of the `$title` of the actual resource since it's not set at that point.